# event listen for click in HTML getting the value

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to reprogram a calculator using the eventListener as it should make the code better overall. However I am having trouble getting the value from the html to use it in the javascript!

Here is the JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zrm9L0u9/

And here is the code

```
var input = document.getElementById("calculator").addEventListener("click", calc);


function calc(a) {
    input = this.a;
    console.log(input);
}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: where is the fiddle?

Comment: my bad  - http://jsfiddle.net/zrm9L0u9/

Answer (score 1):

You wanted something like this I suppose, `calc` is passed `event` object, through which you can take the value.

```
function calc(a) {
    var input = a.target
    console.log(input.value);
}
```

### Edit:

After seeing fiddle, `calculator` turned out to be a div, do not know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I still get an issue when I click a number I just get undefined as if its passing through no value :S

Comment: What I am trying to do is anything in the div 'calculator' once a button is pressed it should then send the value of that button to the function everytime it is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I think span is not supposed to have 'value' attribute. That's why you can't get it from '.value'
Try:

```
function calc(a) {
    input = a.srcElement;
    console.log(input.getAttribute("value"));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

(this) can be used to access a variable present in an html element, but to get the value of an html element from within a function, you should use .innerHTML.

Here is more about (this). [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)